# Gerar nome único para arquivo após upload

Tags: php

Seguinte, tenho um form de upload para que o usuário possa postar algumas imagens, e é necessário que ele esteja logado para postar, em cada postagem o número máximo de imagens permitidas é 5, estava seguindo essa ideia para criar o nome do arquivo:

**id_do_usuario_logado** - **id_do_post** + '__infixo_'+ **numero_da_image**, seria algo como isso:

1-5_infixo_1.jpg

1-5_infixo_2.jpg

Onde 1 é o id do usuário logado, 5 é o id da postagem mais algum infixo qualquer e o número seria gerado por um laço de repetição ,um foreach por exemplo.
O problema disso é que o id da postagem só será gerado após o sucesso do upload então não poderia usa-lo para renomear o arquivo, como posso criar um arquivo com nome único seguindo uma lógica semelhante?

Answer (score 1):

Se for só gerar um nome único podes usar `md5` e `uniqid` mais o `timestamp` ex:

```
$novaimagem = md5(uniqid()) . '-' . time() . '.jpg';

// exemplo de saída: e9ec23688ceedd4039c527b898575126-1473293386.jpg
```

Se tiver que usar o id de seu usuário:

```
$novaimagem = $_SESSION['USER-ID'] . '-' . md5(uniqid()) . '-' . time() . '.jpg';

// exemplo de saída: userID-e9ec23688ceedd4039c527b898575126-1473293386.jpg
```

Note: se seu sistema de cadastro de usuários já prove uma sequência lógica que não repetira o id nem precisa se preocupar com o `md5` além do que o timestamp é sempre sequencial.

Comment: Então, o id do usuário e a postagem são únicos, mas como não posso usar o id da postagem antes de criar ela tive que criar de outra forma, o timestamp pega o tempo exato que foi criado? ano,mês,dia,hora,minutos e segundos?

Comment: Coloquei time na resposta pois ele retorna um numero crescente (UNIX) fazendo assim com que seu novo arquivo tenha o id do usuário (nunca ira salvar com outro id) e o time que nunca repetira. Voçê pode ler mais sobre time no Manual do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php e caso queira recupar um timestamp use date para formatar: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php se a resposta foi útil sinalize