# como enviar um arquivo com mesmo nome sem substituir em php

Tags: php, arquivo

```
<?php
$dir = "arquivo";
$file = $_FILES["csv1"];
if (file_exists('arquivo/dados.csv')) {
    echo "Um arquivo já foi enviado! Envie outro arquivo!";
    exit;
} else {

    if (move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], "{$dir}/dados.csv")) {
        echo "Arquivo enviado com sucesso!";
    } else {
        echo "Erro, o arquivo não pode ser enviado.";
    }
}
```

Comment: como que eu faço isso? tipo se adicionar outro ele substitui não adiciona um novo arquivo

Comment: `"{$dir}/dados.csv"` será o nome do arquivo que você salvará no servidor. Basta mudar o valor de `dados.csv`

Comment: mas eu quero adicionar arquivos csv dois com mesmo nome sera que tem como ?

Comment: Outra [Gerar nome único para arquivo após upload](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151623/5878)

Comment: não entendi essas maneiras como você faria ?

Comment: Dessas formas, gerando um nome único para cada arquivo enviado...

Comment: edita o codigo pra mim ver como vc faria é que não manjo muito de php kk